# 2 Window 1 WindowController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, xib

I have a small problem. I'm still learning Cocoa and I successfully made couple of projects, but I decided to do something different.
The other day I was doing something on my Windows machine using C# (passing data between forms) and it worked flawlessly.
The idea was to have one form which can't be editable just to show the info, and have another one to change the info that should be displayed (recordset example) 
Now I've wanted to do something similar with Cocoa, so I decided to use 2 XIB's (Windows) and 1 controller. And I purposely avoided using CoreData and ArrayController.

I managed to add outlets and a controller that binds all of this together. 
Because I don't have enough space to paste all of the code here I UL'ed it onto [GitHub](https://github.com/mutantkeyboard/Test/tree/master/TestCase)
Everything works fine, but I can't get the values saved in one window updated on the other. 
I just wonder where I went wrong. 
I'd appreciate some help if possible. 
Thank you in advance.

here are the problematic snippets  of code

```
     - (IBAction)changeValues:(id)sender {
windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"Changer" owner:self];
[_displayWindow close];
[windowController showWindow:self];
}
```

and then I have another function which causes me troubles with saving

```
     - (IBAction)storeChanges:(id)sender {

NSString *pName = [_name stringValue];
NSString *pSurname = [_surname stringValue];
NSDate *pDate = [_dateOfBirth dateValue];
NSImage *pImage = [_imageView image];
NSString *pAdditionalData = [_additionalData string];
[_changerWindow close];
[windowController setWindow:_displayWindow];
[_displayWindow update];
[windowController showWindow:self];
}
```

Comment: if you purposely avoided using core-data, why did you tag this question *with* core-data?

Comment: It was a typing mistake, it was supposed to be an xcode. I apologize. Tag has been changed

Comment: I see no where in the code you've posted, anything to do with saving or passing data. I see you putting the values into variables and then doing nothing with them. Where is the relevant code ?

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot to write down the designated initializer call. The idea was to pass the values to the designated initializer before it's updated... `[self initWithName:pName aSurname:pSurname aDOB:pDate anImage:nil anAdditionalData:pAdditionalData];`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort things out. I didn't actually make a proper properties from the second window that would interact with the first one.